# Which Product or Platform should I use to produce pdf files (on the server side) based on templates defined by the user

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat

I have to identify a solution (based on commercial or open source SW) that allows me to do the following:

1) Give the user a templating environment where he can define (hopefully with some visual tools) the template of a document, specifying where variable data will have to show up

2) Have programming APIs that allows a server side program (e.g. running on Node or Java App Server) to produce a pdf document using one of the defined templates - through such API the server side program needs to be able to pass also the required data that will fill the template

3) Get an handle to the pdf produced

In this case, documents are reports that will show information related to a single person/company in a tabular form with potentially some simple graphs (e.g. barcharts, pies) plus some logos.

So, the report would have:

1. Logo and data about the Company issuing the report
2. Some information about the Individual/company requesting the report
3. a series of data about the company/person requiring the report divided in section (header and detail lines) - in each section there may be a simple graph

At the end a very standard document. The key point here is the possibility for an end user to be able to change the template of the report, so that he can drive (at least up to a certain extent) the format of the report itself without having necessarily to code

Can anybody suggest a solution that can fit such requirement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, it's a matter of what does the document looks like eventually. Would it require fancy features that a software like InDesign would offer, or do you have very advanced typographic needs ? Is it more about documentation or basic layout ?
Depending on the expectation, solutions can be XSL-FO (XML to PDF), Callas PDFChip (html to Prepress PDF), InDesign Server (injecting XML into Templates or using EasyCatalog plugin with IDS), XFDF (xml into PDF form), PitStop Server and Smart Preflight, ChiliPublish, DALIM…
Once again, it's all about document layout, needs and budget.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question with some details about the expected documents. I hope this can help provide me some more details.

Comment: Reading at the refinements, I would suggest InDesign Server. An end-user can set a layout with the creative app. He doesn't need to code but he will or someone else have to either datamerge tag or XML Tag the document for variables. 
Then you can drive InDesign Server through SOAP and ExtendScript files to populate the document. Icing on the cake you can choose whatever output format you need. The standard is PDF but you may choose to output an InDesign document that the user may want to refine. 
At any stage, end user can edit template given that he doesn't mess with variables and w/o code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with XMPie.
https://www.xmpie.com/

In the XMPie world, your specific requirements call for a XLIM product in uStore. Or a more complex solution outside of XLIM.

You could also pull it off with an indesign server, some indesign scripts, and a well thought web interface.

You could probably also replace the indesign server with the `itextsharp` library(c#) and create the PDFs through your own code.